# Why doesn't a website display properly in Google Chrome normal mode but displays fine in Incognito mode and all other browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, zurb-foundation, incognito-mode

In my end the webpage looks good but in my client's end the page **doesn't load properly** or just the **vertical lines** show up without the text and images.

Link to the website : http://www.krishnaprasad.me/Iadmire.html (*Inactive now*).

The website looks fine in all browsers for my client except `Google Chrome` that too in normal mode.

I've used `Foundation 5` framework for developing this site. If it's an issue with browser's extensions/plugins at my client's side, can I automatically disable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the easy part: You **cannot** disable a plugin or extension from within JavaScript (if that's what you meant by `automatically` disabling). The only way that I know of to disabling those is for the user to actually open the `Extensions` page in their `Browser Settings` and **manually disable** those.

You can, however, detect the presence of problematic plugins or extensions in JavaScript and, for example, redirect the user to another page where you ask them to disable those plugins.

I've taken a look at the page and I found the culprit: One of elements had an `id` of `adcontent`, which I am guessing is **black-listed** by either Chrome or one of the plugins.

I believe that if you could change that id to something else, and adjust the CSS appropriately, the issue should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'll fix that and check the site again

Comment: Splendid, happy that it did. Would you kindly assign my answer as the right one?